# Simple tutorial overlay for comment toolbar for first-time user on Android app

Tags: feature-request, comments, android-app

The new comment interface is nice and simple, but an overlay at the first time with a simple tutorial will be nice.

Also, there's an option to upvote but no option to remove the upvote.

Comment: Don't think it's a bug, it's consistent with the desktop site where we can't undo comment upvotes. (unless it's done shortly after upvoting, before reloading)

Comment: I was not sure whether to tag this as [tag:bug] or [tag:feature-request] since your question contains both. In the end, I chose [tag:feature-request] since it seems it's the main concern here. Consider post the other issue as a separate post if you want.